# initialise a blank QImage with pyside

Tags: python, qt, pyside

Im trying to initialise a blank QImage widget in a pyside gui but its throwing errors and I cant figure out what I'm supposed to do from the docs, does anyone know what steps i need to do to get this QImage Widget working

```
import sys
from PySide import QtGui, QtCore
import os

class ms_ImageViewer(QtGui.QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super(ms_ImageViewer, self).__init__()
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):               

        main_layout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
        self.setLayout(main_layout)

        self.image = QtGui.QImage(50, 50, QtGui.QImage.Format_Indexed8)
        self.image.fill(QtGui.qRgb(50,50,50))
        button = QtGui.QPushButton('select file', self)
        main_layout.addWidget(button)
        main_layout.addWidget(self.image)

        self.setGeometry(300, 300, 600, 30)
        self.setWindowTitle('ms_image_viewer')    
        self.show()

def main():

    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = ms_ImageViewer()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

and here's the error i get:

```
 /projects/Mayaseed/src/tools/ms_image_viewer.py 
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/projects/Mayaseed/src/tools/ms_image_viewer.py", line 34, in <module>
        main()
      File "/projects/Mayaseed/src/tools/ms_image_viewer.py", line 29, in main
        ex = ms_ImageViewer()
      File "/projects/Mayaseed/src/tools/ms_image_viewer.py", line 9, in __init__
        self.initUI()
      File "/projects/Mayaseed/src/tools/ms_image_viewer.py", line 20, in initUI
        main_layout.addWidget(self.image)
    TypeError: 'PySide.QtGui.QBoxLayout.addWidget' called with wrong argument types:
      PySide.QtGui.QBoxLayout.addWidget(PySide.QtGui.QImage)
    Supported signatures:
      PySide.QtGui.QBoxLayout.addWidget(PySide.QtGui.QWidget, int = 0, PySide.QtCore.Qt.Alignment = 0)
```

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: when giving this answer, the question was a different one than now...

fill expects an int argument instead of a QColor element.

Use

```
self.image.fill(qRgb(50,50,50))
```

instead of

```
self.image.fill(QtGui.QColor(50,50,50))
```

I hope this works exactly the same on pyside as in c++. 
Here is the documentation: http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/qcolor.html#qRgb

Comment: Thanks I fixed that error in the above example but i get an error in adding the Qimage to the layout

Comment: You can't add a QImage to the layout, because it's not a QWidget. Again I hope this works the same way on pyside: You can set the image to a QLabel, and then add the QLabel to the layout.

Comment: right again! playing it inside a QLabel got it displaying, the only problem is that it looks like im getting junk color values displaying... perhaps the `QtGui.qRgb(255,0,0)` isn't working correctly

Comment: I found this in the QImage constructor documentation: "Drawing into a QImage with QImage::Format_Indexed8 is not supported". Probably that is the problem... Try using QImage::Format_ARGB32_Premultiplied

Comment: I want to correct this: If the QImage is indexed, `fill(unsigned int)` expects a color table index (0...255); if it is not, it expects a `qRgb(r, g, b)` argument. Note that `QImage::fill` is not a painting operation. By "painting", they mean using a QPainter.

Answer (score 0):

The main issue is that a QImage is not a widget so it cannot be added to a layout. Below is the code for initialising the Qimage with a red background and placing it inside a QLabel widget. I also change the image format to ARGB32 so that the image is formatted with 4 x 8 bit values for Alpha, Red, Green and blue.

```
import sys
from PySide import QtGui, QtCore
import os

class ms_ImageViewer(QtGui.QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super(ms_ImageViewer, self).__init__()
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):               

        main_layout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
        self.setLayout(main_layout)

        self.image = QtGui.QImage(100, 150, QtGui.QImage.Format_ARGB32)
        intial_color = QtGui.qRgb(189, 149, 39)
        self.image.fill(QtGui.qRgb(255,0,0))
        # self.image.load('/projects/test.png')
        image_label = QtGui.QLabel(" ")
        image_label.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap.fromImage(self.image))
        button = QtGui.QPushButton('select file', self)
        main_layout.addWidget(button)
        main_layout.addWidget(image_label)

        self.setGeometry(300, 300, 600, 30)
        self.setWindowTitle('ms_image_viewer')    
        self.show()

def main():

    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = ms_ImageViewer()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Why do you set the label text to `" "` rather than a null QString?